# Why cant i read the CSV file?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I have this in Visual Studio and cant read the csv file.
The csv file is local in Visual studio.

See the code below

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="dygraph.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="dygraph.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv2"
  style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g2 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
    "temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file
    {}          // options
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot open files from File System in browser like that

Comment: Is there a request from the browser for "temperatures.csv"? And does it succeed?

Comment: @DevMayukh, What is your solution?

Comment: @phuzi , No, thats all code i have on my cshtml side.

Comment: That's not what I meant. With this code in the browser, does the browser make a request (XHR/AJAX/Fetch) to the server for "temperatures.csv" that is initiated by dygraph.js?

Comment: @phuzi, no nothing like that

Comment: Any other errors on the console?